# Cannot ignore class ans wsdl files in SourceTree

Tags: gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

I have bunch of .class and .wsdl files which simple are not ignored by SourceTree - ignore command in the drop down menu is not active

[image]

My `.gitignore` file looks like

```
#
# Default excludes
#

# Binaries
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip
*.war
*.ear
*.sar
*.class

# Maven 
target/

# IntelliJ project files 
*.iml
*.iws
*.ipr
.idea/

# Unknown
**/jaxws/*
**/wsdl/*
```

Any clue what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time has passed since you asked this question, but looking at the color of the icon on the left of your files, it looks like you have already tracked those files, therefore you can't ignore them.
First you need to choose the option `Stop Tracking` bellow `Ignore` and after that you will be able to select those files and ignore them.